Is it Possible to Include CSS Files in TSX Watch Mode
I am using the tsx package to monitor typescript files and live reload my express server when a change is made to any of its dependencies. I would like to also refresh the page when a CSS file is changed so that I can see the results. Is switching to nodemon and ts-node the only way to do this?
I have looked through the docs but can only find ways to ignore files, not add them to the watchlist.

tsx watch is for imported files. Unless you have a frontend app with custom file loaders that could import css (which tsx isn't suitable for any way), then this is not the case. Use a separate watcher like nodemon
